# How to send requests to server one after one RxJS?

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5, rxjs6

How to correctly send RxJS requests, when there are 4 different API endpoints, I need to request each endpoint until previous does not return data.

**Schema is:**

```
Request 1 -> Return Void
Request 2 -> Returned data, stop working and return data
Request 3 -> Will fail
```

**Result is:**

Only one result from one of request.

**I tried this:**

```
req1$ = of(response);
req2$ = of(response);

req1$.pipe( flatMap((result) => {
   if (result) { return of(result); } else {return of([]);}
}));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to do a manual chain, something like:

```js
const getValueFromServer$  = req1$.pipe(flatMap => result ? of(result) : firstFallback$);
const firstFallback$       = req2$.pipe(flatMap => result ? of(result) : secondFallback$)
const secondFallback$      = req3$.pipe(flatMap => result ? of(result) : req4$)

getValueFromServer$.subscribe(console.log)
```

Comment: Could you edit the code in question, it is hard to understand what is observer first and etc.

Comment: On which observer subscribe?